# Linux embedded system: detect power on USB (as USB device)

Tags: linux, usb, power-supply, power, embedded

I'm working on a Linux embedded system that can draw its power from two distinct sources:

- a dedicated power supply
- power supply through USB (connected to an external USB host)

I must know when the device is unplugged, so I can do an emergency shutdown.

I know how to detect when my dedicated power supply disappears.

But I don't know when the USB power supply is unplugged.

How would you detect when a USB cable is unplugged from an USB device under Linux ?

Thanks in advance for your insights.

Comment: Please state the Linux distribution you are using/plan on using, because a lot depends on that.

Comment: We're building a root filesystem using Yocto for a processor ARM (IMX6UL). We're using Variscite repositories for their processor and custom layers for our applications. Thanks for your reading.

Comment: If you look in your log file does it genetate any messages when the cable is plugged in/unplugged? If it revignises a device you can use udev to trigger actions when things are inserted/removed.  Fail2ban might also be a hacky option.

Comment: Thank you for your advice and information, I've tried a few things on these lines. Eventually, we managed to fix the problem by including GadgetFs code to our app,  to manage the connection/deconnection to an USB host... It seems to work so far. Thanks again.